# Chrome freezes Ubuntu GNOME 15.04

Tags: gnome, google-chrome

Every time I open Google Chrome it freezes GNOME. The mouse can still move, but I can't so much as toggle to a terminal screen (with alt-f1, etc.).

In the past these sorts of issues have seemed to stem from problems with the proprietary NVidia graphics drivers. For the record, currently I am running a fresh install of Ubuntu GNOME 15.04 after a DBAN of my previous system. I am using the built-in Nouveaux drivers. Also for some reason my graphics shows up as "Gallium 0.4 on NVC4" rather than the name of my actual graphics card (a GTX 460). Some searching suggests this is the name of the OGL rendering engine?

Anyhow, http://notepad.cc/share/0zu6nQ0GG3 <- that is a dump of my lshw in case it can be helpful. If any other information would be useful, please let me know. I'd like to get this fixed so I can stop using Firefox.

Comment: Install Nvidia drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Nvidia proprietary drivers by running

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346
```

in terminal. Then reboot.

Comment: I used Synaptic to install it, but either way it fixed my problem. Kudos.